# Stripe does not work correctly - invoice paid but it does not send randomly 'invoice.payment_succeeded' webhook response - bug?

Tags: django, paypal, stripe-payments, webhooks, payment

I am using Stripe Webhook and this is phenomenal. I use Stripe webhook in my Django app like this:

```
class StripeView(GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserNameSerializer

    def post(self, request):

        payload = request.body
        event = None

        try:
            event = stripe.Event.construct_from(
                json.loads(payload), stripe.api_key
            )
        except ValueError as e:
            # Invalid payload
            return HttpResponse(status=400)

        print(event.type)

        if event.type == 'invoice.payment_succeeded':

            payment_invoice = event.data.object

            ...
```

Every single time I use exactly the same method exactly the same way and it is executed without any errors in the same way. It looks like this:

```
customer = stripe.Customer.create(
    email=user.email,
    source=request.data['token']
)

subscription = stripe.Subscription.create(
    customer=customer.id,
    items=[
        {
            'plan': 'plan_H8K23228WmaQM',
            'quantity': request.data['amount'],
        },
    ],
    expand=['latest_invoice.payment_intent'],
)
```

Once Stripe generate requests in this way:

```
2020-06-05 22:48:21   --> payment_method.attached [evt_no]
2020-06-05 22:48:21  <--  [400] POST http://localhost:8007/stripe/ [evt_no]
2020-06-05 22:48:22   --> customer.created [evt_no]
2020-06-05 22:48:22  <--  [400] POST http://localhost:8007/stripe/ [evt_no]
2020-06-05 22:48:23   --> charge.succeeded [evt_no]
2020-06-05 22:48:23  <--  [400] POST http://localhost:8007/stripe/ [evt_no]
2020-06-05 22:48:23   --> invoice.created [evt_no]
2020-06-05 22:48:23  <--  [400] POST http://localhost:8007/stripe/ [evt_no]
2020-06-05 22:48:24   --> invoice.finalized [evt_no]
2020-06-05 22:48:24  <--  [400] POST http://localhost:8007/stripe/ [evt_no]
2020-06-05 22:48:24   --> payment_intent.succeeded [evt_no]
2020-06-05 22:48:24  <--  [400] POST http://localhost:8007/stripe/ [evt_no]
2020-06-05 22:48:27   --> customer.source.created [evt_no]
2020-06-05 22:48:27  <--  [400] POST http://localhost:8007/stripe/ [evt_no]
```

Other times he does it this way:

```
2020-06-05 23:16:22   --> customer.created [evt_no]
2020-06-05 23:16:22  <--  [400] POST http://localhost:8007/stripe/ [evt_no]
2020-06-05 23:16:25   --> customer.subscription.created [evt_no]
2020-06-05 23:16:25  <--  [400] POST http://localhost:8007/stripe/ [evt_no]
2020-06-05 23:16:25   --> payment_method.attached [evt_no]
2020-06-05 23:16:25  <--  [400] POST http://localhost:8007/stripe/ [evt_no]
2020-06-05 23:16:26   --> customer.source.created [evt_no]
2020-06-05 23:16:26  <--  [400] POST http://localhost:8007/stripe/ [evt_no]
2020-06-05 23:16:27   --> invoice.created [evt_no]
2020-06-05 23:16:27  <--  [400] POST http://localhost:8007/stripe/ [evt_no]
2020-06-05 23:16:28   --> payment_intent.created [evt_no]
2020-06-05 23:16:28  <--  [400] POST http://localhost:8007/stripe/ [evt_no]
2020-06-05 23:16:28   --> charge.succeeded [evt_no]
2020-06-05 23:16:28  <--  [400] POST http://localhost:8007/stripe/ [evt_no]
2020-06-05 23:16:29   --> invoice.finalized [evt_no]
2020-06-05 23:16:29  <--  [400] POST http://localhost:8007/stripe/ [evt_no]
2020-06-05 23:16:29   --> payment_intent.succeeded [evt_no]
2020-06-05 23:16:29  <--  [400] POST http://localhost:8007/stripe/ [evt_no]
2020-06-05 23:16:29   --> customer.updated [evt_no]
2020-06-05 23:16:29   --> invoice.payment_succeeded [evt_no]
2020-06-05 23:16:29  <--  [400] POST http://localhost:8007/stripe/ [evt_no]
2020-06-05 23:16:30  <--  [200] POST http://localhost:8007/stripe/ [evt_no]
```

And the biggest paradox is that in both cases in my Stripe dashboard invoice payment is succeeded. It does not matter whether I get `invoice.payment_succeeded` or not. In addition, these responses with `invoice.payment_succeeded` status appear to be random. Once, when I call this method, I get the status `invoice.payment_succeeded` and the next two times I do not etc. Any ideas what is wrong? I have wasted a lot of my time because of it.

Comment: You're getting a lot of 400 responses, are you catching the real issue in your try/except?

Comment: @IainShelvington Because at the end I have `else: return HttpResponse(status=400)`. Do you have any ideas what may be wrong and how can I solve this?

Comment: @IainShelvington I checked it and no error was found in try catch Invalid payload so all 400 are returned in `else`.

Comment: @JohnSmith could you clarify your question? I am not sure I understand: "It is not known when he suddenly does not send a request invoice.payment_succeeded after a correct transaction although everything has been posted correctly according to the data on the stripe account."

Comment: @hmunoz I updated the question, is it clear now?

Comment: yes, that helps. So basically you're not getting the `invoice.payment_succeeded` event sometimes, and other times you are. Are you seeing any logs in your Stripe CLI's `listen` terminal window? Also, does your Stripe Dashboard show the `invoice.payment_succeeded` event when your Stripe CLI does not?

Comment: @hmunoz Yes, exactly. The logs that I pasted in the question are from `stripe listen --forward-to localhost:8007/stripe/` and in both cases whether I get `invoice.payment_succeeded` or not in Stripe dashboard in Billing>Invoices I see all these invoices with status `payment succeeded`.

Comment: What about on https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/events , if you try again, do you see the `invoice.payment_succeeded` event on the "Events" page on Dashboard but not on CLI, is that right?

Comment: @hmunoz I have no idea but now it seems to we working properly. I have no idea what is going on. Maybe it was just a bug. I will test it all thoroughly so that I can be sure and let you know here in the comment. Will this not be a problem for you?

Comment: Sure, here is good or drop by the support channel ( https://support.stripe.com/contact ) or drop by the #stripe channel on freenode (https://webchat.freenode.net/)